# new :How to show "Processing... " text for few seconds and show "data updated" in html?

Tags: html

I am developing simple html update page.

I have button in one page and clicking on that new window should open.
In the new window i need to show "Processing..." text for few seconds and show text "Data Updated" new page.

Please help me.

Regards,
Sandy

---

HI,

Actually this is next part of question. I am able redirect between pages with new window.
But After displaying the "Data Updated" Page in new window. Now If I close the "Data Updated" Page I want redirect to the original page to in the original window.

Please Help Me.

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which technologies are you using? Basicly you could use some timer object and when few seconds pass automaticly redirect user to new page with text "Data updated"

first page:

```
<FORM>

<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Test" onclick="window.open('http://www.test.com/processingPage');" >

</FORM>
```

processing page:

```
<div id="proccessContent">
Processing...
</div> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=next_page.html">
```

data updated page:

```
<div id="updateContent">
Data updated
</div>
```

this is not complete code but its something to go from.

Comment: Hi Nikola, i am using html and javascript, help me.

Comment: isn't your original window already open and set to original page? or do you close original page after first redirect? how many windows you have? are we talking about windows or tabs?

Comment: @Sandeep212 is your original page opened when you close Data updated page? is it in another window or you close it? do you want to automaticly close the Data updated window or to redirect to original page, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

On First Page you need to have only a button

```
<input type="button" value="Next Page" onclick="window.open('nextpage.html');" />
```

On next Page you need a div and a javascript interval as following

```
<div id='urdiv'>Processing... </div>

<script>
var yourdiv = document.getElementById('urdiv');
setInterval(function() { yourdiv.innerHTML = 'Data Updated'; },5000);
</script>
```

Or if you want to clear the interval (to avoid repetion of no use). Then

```
<script>
var yourdiv = document.getElementById('urdiv');
var myinterval = setInterval(function() { myFunction(); }, 5000);
function myFunction()
{
    yourdiv.innerHTML = 'Data Updated';
    window.clearInterval(myinterval);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is next part of question. I am able redirect between pages with new window.
But After displaying the "Data Updated" Page in new window. Now If I close the "Data Updated" Page I want redirect to the original page to in the original window.